# How to get wifiAccessPoints or Cell Tower objects for google's geolocation API?

Tags: javascript, wifi, google-geolocation

Is there any way to get wifiAccessPoints or Cell Tower objects to apply on [google's geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) request body with Javascript?

I got high number of `accuracy` and from the docs says that because of `wifiAccessPoints` and `cellTowers` objects could not be geolocated.

Comment: Are you indoors or outdoors? What accuracy are you getting? What do you expect?

Comment: Both;
Accuracy can be 900 or higher;
Accurate value of long, lat, accuracy

Comment: Have you set the EnableHighAccuracy flag on your call to watchPosition? You are using watch and not getCurrent right?  The first call is normally inaccurate and then refines. Indoors nothing is guranteed,

Comment: Have you ever got your answer for this? I'm also struggling to find those. my scenario is a little harder, I'm trying to do this with javascript, on client side. if you figured could you share?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JS geolocation object navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
basic syntax... inplace of google?

```
  getCurrentPosition(success);
  getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

see :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition